# MALWARE on my Ubuntu 16.04.01 lts

Tags: malware

I have malware which puts advertising in all my browsers.

Originally I installed Windows 10 and shortly thereafter, my computer was infected.

I erased the hard drive and installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. However, ads still appear in the Firefox browser plus the native Ubuntu web browser. A screenshot to show examples of the ads.

The left side of the picture is an normal browser without infection and the right side is the infected browser. When i see the same page in my other computer looks like the left-side image.

[image: Two browsers: left uninfected, right infected]

PS: Any thoughts on what kind of virus or malware this is?  In the other PC's Firefox browser (Firefox), on the same wifi with the same ISP, infection has not yet appeared.

Comment: Please, dont vote negative if you dont give a usefull answer or an explanation. Do another thing, and dont bother people who really needs help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you sync your history and other bookmarks with other firefox browsers that you use on other systems?

Comment: Thanks george for response!, i made a clean installation without import bookmarks, or plugins or extensions. :)

Comment: The browser on the left has some add-ons. What add-ons are installed and are they also installed in the browser on the right?

Comment: I really ask you to check your router. Try to reflash it. I had similar issues some years ago (long before iot worms have became mainstream), I checked pcs, they were clear. Then I reflashed my router with firmware from vendor website and infection have gone. The easiest way to check if the ads are because of tampering with connection is to open any https website and check if it has the ads you think made by malware.

Comment: Do you have problems when running the live-media (without persistence) in the "try" mode?

Comment: This whole question is hysteria and false premises.  The advertising in question is in the LaVoz page itself (using Javascript and <iframe>s) and is served up by a WWW advertising company called SmartAdServer.  SmartAdServer allows advertisers to target adverts by operating system and WWW browser.  This "MALWARE" hooplah and all of this fumbling around with routers, plug-ins, anti-virus softwares, and even reinstalling operating systems is just nonsense.  Targetted advertising, people.  The advertisers know what your WWW browser and operating system are.

Comment: AlexP I disable all the add ons and still appearing! And in other browser(in other computer) with all defaults addons dont showup this advertising.
KOLANICH I will try your solution today and tomorrow tell you what happend
UBFAN1 When im using ubuntu in a USB LIVE shows the same ads!
JDeBP IM using diferent computers and one show up this advertising and the other no, my cellphone dont show this ADV so, i think what is my computer only :(

Thanks to all for help me! Really :)

Comment: I THINK! What the virus or ADV soft, maybe could stay in the MBR or HDD Firmware! SO im gonna try to make a LOW - LEVEL FORMAT of my hard drive and TELL YOU what happend! IF any has more ideas, im really grateful to hear they! THANKS to all :D

Comment: K7AAY THANKS FOR THE HELP WITH MY ENGLISH!

Answer (score 0):

I would use an AntiVirus vendor solution to examine the PC.
Avira has one available for non-commercial use. You install it on a USB device and then boot to it (which may require adjusting BIOS settings)

Link: https://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system

To your question, this will (hopefully) identify the malware if indeed it exists. Of course, no solution is absolute.

Comment: Thank you MARK, i wil try it right now and later told you whats happend!, i dont kow it what avira has this type of online solutions.

Comment: Don't found nothing with avira. Thanks MARK! :D i will follow your path with online or usb antivirus!

Comment: Sophos offers a free antivirus for home use that works very well with ubuntu (16.04 & 16.10 at least) https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx - Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is adverts showing up indiscriminately it would suggests that you may have inadvertently installed an add-on from a site you visited.

Now that being said if you have `sync` enabled between browsers then when ever you install it `syncs` and re-install the problem.

Do a total disabling of all third party plugins and see if it solves the issue. If it remains then disable all plugins in your browser then check again.

Less I forget if `sync` is enabled disable it.

Please post results and good luck.

Comment: Thank you GEORGE! i disable all things and still appearing!.

Comment: do you have `clamav` ? if you do run a full system scan

Comment: I will try it CLAMAV tonight and tomorrow tell you, thanks George!

Comment: use this command `sudo clamscan -r --infected --bell  / ` when you do so it lists infected files, then when your sure no `system files` gave a `false positive` you can now do `sudo clamscan -r --remove /` to remove them. Best of luck

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

For everybody who HAS a problem like me, i dont found a solution. The only solution is a low level format and reinstal everything!. Meanwhile i have a usefull and wonderfull browser named BRAVE. This browser blocks every advertising from the malware who try to put in my webpages so, its a "temporal" solution. The malware and me, meanwhile still living togheter, in company until im format my hard disk. But thanks to this browser, them cant take money from ads, so, i recommend it to all who is tired to se advertising everywhere. THANK YOU SO MUCH, to the community for help me and support me. My greetings to all!!